# Failed to codesign since macOS Sonoma

Tags: flutter, xcode, codesign

after many hours looking for a solution I hope to find one here :) I am creating an ios application using flutter. Since updating my macbook to MacOs Sonoma it is impossible for me to launch an archive of the application on Xcode (the error below is displayed). I can launch my application on Simulator but not on a physical phone either.

error: Target release_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Failed to codesign /Users/etiennemary/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hcgaysxersoeaugykishvsewlgps/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Flutter.framework/Flutter with identity ...... /Users/etiennemary/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hcgaysxersoeaugykishvsewlgps/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Flutter.framework/Flutter: replacing existing signature Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Development: Etienne Mary (. )" /Users/etiennemary/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hcgaysxersoeaugykishvsewlgps/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Flutter.framework/Flutter: errSecInternalComponent Failed to package /Applications/aa/evento.

By searching I thought I understood that it could come from Icloud but even if I put my App in the Application folder, I got this error.